# Error in node module while extending theme msdyn365

Tags: reactjs, sdk, node-modules, e-commerce, msdyn365bc

I am trying to add a textbox in a predefined module in msdyn 365 SDK. I am trying to achieve this by extending a theme to add module-extensions. But once I add a module-extension by extending a theme, I am facing some errors in node modules? What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to resolve this?

I extended the theme using the following command syntax:

yarn msdyn365 add-view-extension spring product-feature